# Output of PHP script in C#

Tags: c#, get

The main problem I think is that I am trying to get an output of a php script on an ssl protected website. Why doesn't the following code work?

```
            string URL = "https://mtgox.com/api/0/data/ticker.php";
            HttpWebRequest myRequest =
             (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            myRequest.Method = "GET";
            WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader _sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(),
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            string result = _sr.ReadToEnd();
            //Console.WriteLine(result);
            result = result.Replace('\n', ' ');
            _sr.Close();
            myResponse.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

It hangs at WebException was unhandeled The operation has timed out

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting the wrong url. ssl is `https://`, but you're hitting `http://` (note the lack of **S**). The site does redirect to the SSL version of the page, but your code is apparently not following that redirect.

Comment: Yes sorry I had just changed it to http:// instead of https before posting to test that I cannot get access to the http one

Answer (score 0):

Have added             myRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11"; everything started working